# Como debugar uma aplicação C# MVC externamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Gostaria de saber se há como debugar uma aplicação MVC C# externamente, tentei usar o IIS Express, mais sem sucesso, alguém já passou por esta situação ou melhor, alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Gostaria de acessar a minha aplicação em outro computador da mesma rede, como faço para configurar a minha aplicação e como diz a pergunta eu quero "debugar" a minha aplicação. :)

Comment: Não, e se eu quisesse utilizar essa minha aplicação em rede, como faria?

Comment: Ishh meu amigo, acho que você não entendeu, e não está me ajudando, sim eu já ouvi falar em SVN e TFS, o que isso ajudaria no meu assunto?

Comment: Sua pergunta tem vários sentidos. O que exatamente você quer fazer? Debbug remoto ou simplesmente acessar a aplicação?

Comment: os dois, mais principalmente acessar

Comment: Então, qual o problema com a resposta do wesleydsantos? Porque o IIS Express e o IIS são coisas distintas. E para poder instalar, você precisa saber a versão do seu windows que está instalada e se ja tiver instalado, precisa garantir que o suporte ao .net está instalado junto com o iis e que ele está configurado para responder na interface de rede de onde vem o acesso. Qual a mensagem de erro que você recebe ao acessar a aplicação?

Comment: Não falei em algum momento que a resposta dele estava com problema. Estou testando aqui ainda. Leia primeiro atentamente antes de fazer uma crítica construtiva. :)

Comment: Deixando teu comentário sem sentido pra lá e sendo objetivo tecnicamente, 1 - você já publicou uma aplicação asp.net antes? 2  - Você já instalou um IIS antes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você está usando o IIS instalado na sua maquina, ou você esta usando o ISS express ( Aquele que quando a gente aperta F5 ele sobre a aplicação) .
Se tiver usando o express, instale o ISS 7.5 na sua maquina, ele é encontrado facilmente no site da microsoft.

Entao vamos lá: ..

- 1- voce vai instalar o IIS 7.5
- 2- você vai publicar a sua aplicação, e depois de publicada, voce vai
  você vai pegar os arquivos , ir em C:\ e colocar os arquivos dentro
  da pasta c:\inetpub
- 3- você verifica qual ip está na sua maquina abra o cmd e degite
  ipconfig.. verifique qual é o ipv4 da sua maquina..
- 4- suponhamos que seu ip seja 192.168.1.101, entao você vai entrar no
  seu roteador, e apontar a porta 80, para o seu ip, exemplo
  <192.168.1.101>
- 3 - então você vai ir em outra maquina , abrir o seu navegador e vai
  digitar o ip da maquina onde se encontra o IIS instalado, no caso do
  nosso exemplo é 192.168.1.101. entao voce digitar 192.168.1.101:80 e
  pronto !